# fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found 1>Done building project "project.vcxproj" -- FAILED

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a .dat file using fout in visual studio 2019 but I am encountering the following error

fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found 1>Done building project "project.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ofstream fout("sin.dat");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        fout << i << "   " << sqrt(i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me to create and write a simple file. I am new in visual studio. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your project happen to contain multiple cpp files that all define a `main` function?

Comment: yes, I have two cpp files in my project

Comment: That's what the compiler is complaining about. There can only be one definition of `main` in the entire project. Either exclude the other file from building or move this file to a new project. (either in the same solution or a different solution)